# Cordova build Error for Android So i can't build my solution

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I got a lot of Errors like this, so i can't build my project!
I'm using visual studio 2015.
What is the meaning of this errors?
And How could i solve this problems?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yyVX.png)

```
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 8.0.0 already installed.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:9
1>  C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:9
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  const syntaxErr = e.message.match(/^Unexpected token.*position\s+(\d+)/i)
1>      const syntaxErr = e.message.match(/^Unexpected token.*position\s+(\d+)/i)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^^^^^
1>      ^^^^^
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
1>  SyntaxError Use of const in strict mode.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
1>      at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
1>      at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at require (module.js:384:17)
1>      at require (module.js:384:17)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:12:16)
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:12:16)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This problem might be came from 1)"regedit setting".
Also, it is possible that 2)you try to move program file/android/folders to appdata/android/folders.

I fixed this problem to reinstall android studio and to reset system path related to cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be in `regedit setting`

**OR**

You are trying to move `program file/android/folders` to `appdata/android/folders`.

I fixed this problem by reinstall android studio and reseting the system path related to cordova.